# How to blur part of an Image using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

We have a large number of Images taken from a car for a project. To satisfy privacy norms, we need to detect faces & License Plates and then blur those areas. I came to know of the Emgucv project, and the tutorial given at http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp has been very useful to detect Licensplates.

Is there a way of blurring this region using Emgu itself?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is something built-in like what you are looking for.

What you will have to do, like with openCV, is to blur a whole copy of your source image and then copy back the license plate part to the original image.

You can do this using the [SmoothBlur method](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/4d3d4a90-feb3-ff76-0471-7ae2d3917e7c.htm) first and then the [Copy method](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/a9b5bb96-c65e-93d5-330a-13ad618563e6.htm) that accepts a mask as its second argument.