# Blur only a part of a picture in EmguCV by using the return value from DetectHaarCascade

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, blur

I know that you can blur out a whole picture by using Emgu's functions like `SmoothBlur` or `GaussianBlur`.

What I am interested in, is to know if it is possible to apply this filter only to a certain region of an image, for example the return-value of the function `DetectHaarCascade`, to blur out all recognized objects(faces, hands, bananas,...) inside an Image by using Emgu? I have managed to draw a rectangle around the detected region so far, therefore I thought it should be possible to apply a filter to this region?

I have tried a solution similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195138/gaussian-blurring-with-opencv-only-blurring-a-subregion-of-an-image), but I can't pass the parameter returned from the `DetectHaarCascade`-Function to the Rectangle.

Does anyone know a better solution to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to blur part of an Image using EmguCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009180/how-to-blur-part-of-an-image-using-emgucv)

Comment: I could think of: make copy of image, convert region to rectangle (you must replace hairs outside with the same color as on edge of region, otherwise e.g. hair will get blurred into face), blur rectangle, mask with original image without face... if you really must use rectangle.

Comment: my bad, you are right, I did not found that. But I am asking if it is possible to apply a blur filter to the return Value of a `DetectHaarCascade`.

Comment: Yes, It might be possible to do it your way, but I thought it would be easier just to blur out the rectange returned from the function...